# Finding 90deg intersection point between two lines

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

Finding 90deg intersection point between two lines

I have two connected lines and their respective starting and ending points. So suppose i have this:

```
 Line1: (25,25 - 75, 25) width - 50m
 Line2: (25,75 - 25,25) width - 50m
```

(This lines are drawed on svg, so the y axis start from top to bottom)

Currently, i have a formula that already calculates correctly the angle between this two lines:

```js
     const dx1 = line1.x2 - line1.x1;
     const dy1 = line1.y2 - line1.y1;
     const dx2 = line2.x2 - line2.x1;
     const dy2 = line2.y2 - line2.y1;
     const angle1 = Math.atan2(dy1, dx1) * 180 / Math.PI;
     const angle2 = Math.atan2(dy2, dx2) * 180 / Math.PI;
     const angle_diff = Math.abs(angle1 - angle2);`
```

Now, what i want is a way to find a new intersection point between the two lines, when they are near a 90deg angle, that would connect them on a 90deg angle. The example above already connect them on a 90deg angle, but i have a drag feature in this svg where i can move the point connecting both lines, and i want a way to make it easier to force both lines to be perpendicular when near the 90deg angle. I always have at my disposal the current starting and ending points of both lines and their widths, any ideas?

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sclm.png)

Comment: When two lines are close to 90 degrees - what parameter you want to change to provide exactly 90? Perhaps one line if fixed, and far point of another line is fixed too, and you want to move intersection point?

Comment: Yes, i want to move the intersection point of both lines to get to a 90deg angle, i'll post a picture to clarify a bit

Comment: OK. What about lines lengths or other conditions? There is infinite number of points providing perp lines with fixed far ends. Here seems lines should be perp to l2, l3, but what about general case?

Comment: Here's a solution that will keep the slope of one of the lines fixed. https://www.varsitytutors.com/act_math-help/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-perpendicular-line

Comment: Why would you need to calculate two angles? You're working in a plane, so if you compute one angle, the other angle is, by definition, 180 degrees (or pi) minus the one you computed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the circle as shown in figure below.
Positions on this circle satisfy the condition (90 degrees).

Orange point is you are dragging, and green position will be good candidate position to modify, I think.

[image]